# Let $G$ be a finite group of even order. Then which of the following statements is correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be a finite group of even order. Then which of the following
>   statements is correct ?
>
> $1.$ The number of elements of order $2$ in $G$ is even
>
> $2.$ The number of elements of order $2$ in $G$ is odd
>
> $3.$ G has no subgroup of order $2$
>
> $4.$ None of the above.

---

My attempt : I take $G=  K_4   $, then option $1$ is correct

Is it true  ?

Any hints/solution

Thank you!

Comment: Whatever $K_4$ is, it isn't every possible group of even order.

Comment: I'm guessing $K_4$ is the Klein 4-group, which has three elements of order 2.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown   $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$   for  $n=1,2,3.......$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1 is false, actually the group $K_4$ has $3$ elements of order $2$

---

The group $G$ must has an element of order $2$ is true, and it is an easy exercise to you!

If $a \neq a^{-1}$, then $\vert a \vert$ is not $2$, so this type of elements comes in pairs, which make an even count. Call this count as $k$, then

$$\vert G \vert =\underbrace{\vert \{e\} \vert}_{1} + \underbrace{\vert \{a \in G :a \neq a^{-1} \} \vert}_{k\;\; \text{an even count}} +\text{number of remaining order $2$ elements}$$

But Whole count is even, so the last count must be ODD!

Option $3$ is obviously false!

Comment: im not getting   why u write  $ |G|= 1  + k  $?

Comment: That means  $$\vert G \vert=\vert \{e\} \vert + \vert \{a \in G :a \neq a^{-1} \} \vert +\text{number of remaining order $2$ elements}  $$

Answer (score 1):

As given that group $G$ is of even order so number of elements of order $2$ should be odd since any element of order $2$ is self inverse and any other element of order more than $2$ must appear in the group with its inverse element also so total number of elements in finite group of even order is number of self inverse elements+number of nonself inverse elements clearly number of non self order elements are even and in any group identity element is always self inverse so number of elements of order $2$ should be odd(since self inverse elements other than identity are of order $2$ only). Therefore option $1$ is false, for example you can consider $S_3$ group of symmetry on $3$ symbols it has $3$ elements of order $2$. So option $2$ s correct. Option $3$ can be easily discarded using the Syllow theorem.

Comment: Suppose $G$ is a group of even order and it does not have any element of order 2. Let $a \in G^*$ then o(a)>2 so $a^{-1}$ will be distinct from $a$ and will belong to G. So it can be seen that any element of $G$ other than identity must occur in pair in $G$. So order of $G$ become odd including identity. Which leads to a contradiction. So $G$ will have an element of order 2 so a subgroup of order 2 also.